# Reference with results for common Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I frequently need to know facts about classical Lie algebras like $\mathfrak{su}(n)$, $\mathfrak{so}(n)$, $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$... and do not have time to try and compute all of it. I would like to know if there is a text or table I can use which has the main properties of such algebras, such as the structure constants, dimensionality, characters, ...

In particular, I would like to find a reference with the second Casimir invariant for the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$, for example.

Comment: I am not sure about Casimirs but Bourbaki's book (chapters 4-6 on semisimple Lie algebars) has an appendix containing calculations of standard for all simple Lie algebras. Also, check books by Vinberg and Onischik.

Comment: F. Iachello, *Lie Algebras and Applications*, Lect. Notes Phys. 708 (Springer, Berlin Heidelberg 2006), DOI 10.1007/b11785361,         
ISBN-10 3-540-36236-3        ISBN-13 978-3-540-36236-4

Comment: @Moishe Kohan, Cosmas Zachos: Why not turn those comments into answers?